# Android Layout Design Help

Tags: android, user-interface, tablelayout

I would like to a layout like this one:

```
------------------------------------
SCROLLABLE BAR CONTAINING SOME ITEMS (Invisible)
------------------------------------
A VIEWFLIPPER WITH TWO WEBVIEW (Should fill the entire screen except for some space required for the toolbar)
------------------------------------
ANOTHER SCROLLABLE BAR (Invisible)
------------------------------------
A TOOLBAR-LIKE FIXED-HEIGHT BAR.
```

So I wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_gravity="fill" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scvNotes" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lilNotes" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/vflVisual" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill">
            <WebView android:id="@+id/wvFirst" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill">
            </WebView>
            <WebView android:id="@+id/wvSecond" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill">
            </WebView>
        </ViewFlipper>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scvPages" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lilPages" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:visibility="invisible">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lilToolbar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/btnLibrary" android:src="@drawable/libreria" android:layout_height="44px" android:layout_width="28px">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But it creates a layout with two TableRow visible, and the WebViews are not displayed...
The two scrollable lists must be invisible and made visible if the user requires them by choosing an option on the toolbar..
Which Layout should I use to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Comment: You should go for RelativeLayout .

Answer (score 0):

Second table row use all height available cause u used `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
That's why only two table rows are visible. Try changing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: the problem is that if I use wrap_content on the second row, it won't fill up the entire available space...